# Why are my coldfusion soap webservices 10 times slower in production vs development?

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, apache-axis, coldfusion-10

> **UPDATE**
>
> It appears this issue is caused by a bug related specifically to using Axis2 with ColdFusion and we have been able
> to replicate the issue in our production environment on two different servers by
> switching between Axis1 and Axis2. My original tests to compare the
> two were apparently thwarted by an override in an Application.cfc
> which forced Axis2.
>
> We ran into a memory leak today which forced us to speed up the resolution to this issue. It resembled the leak
> discussed here though we aren't sure if it is the exact same
> problem
> (https://www.hass.de/content/coldfusion-10-webservice-leaking-memory-trusted-cache-leaks-memory).
>
> Our primary webservices are in Axis1 and we only switched to Axis2 for
> this new set of webservices because we needed document literal style
> for SalesForce and with Axis1 an invalid wsdl was being created (did
> not properly describe all object types in arrays). So now we have it as
> Axis1 and using a manually manipulated wsdl. Not entirely sure if it
> will work out with SalesForce but as far as a general fix this works.

I am investigating an issue with our coldfusion based soap webservices in our production environment. It appears that the time between the return statement in the webservices method code and actually receiving a response can be significant and appears to directly correspond to the size of the response and/or number of objects.

In development a particular request that returns 1000 records takes about 6 seconds to return. However in production that same hit takes 50+ seconds to return. I added some timing code and found that the actual function code takes less than 1 second to run at the start of the request, meaning that generating the response is taking coldfusion about 50 seconds in production. Hitting the webservice with simple http request does not have the same slowness so seems to be soap/axis specific. The resulting xml is about 1MB which I have compared and found no differences. I also copied out settings from cfadmin in both environments to compare and could find no performance related setting differences.

Both environments are at the same CF 10 update level. The server monitor shows no significant memory usage. I also ran the request from in the server to make sure there wasn't some slow connection issues or https slowing things down but the results are the same.

Any suggestions or solution would be appreciated.

**Additional notes...**

- CPU sits at about 17% for most of the time of the request which is a lot of work to be doing. Something is happening very inefficiently
- I tried switching instance to Axis1 and back again followed by an instance restart and additional tests with no change in results

Comment: Does it only happen to SOAP requests or does it affect regular requests (of cfm templates) as well?

Comment: Just soap. CF webservices can actually be hit through normal http requests/parameters instead of through soap calls and hitting them in that way does not result in that delay.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you have them throttled - check the "request tuning" in your CF administrator. By default the setting for "number of simultaneous web service requests" is 10. Are you looping and hitting the server? In production is there more traffic?

In server monitor enable profiling and monitoring, then click on "statistics". On the far right there is a little chart icon. click on it and you will see a chart and a counter legend in the top right. Then run your code. Does the "web services running" reach a threshold and cross into "web services queued" - if so you need to increase that threshold.

[image]

One more clue - in the server monitor do NOT run the "memory profiling for more than a few seconds  - say 30. If you don't you will have performance problems for sure.

Comment: thankfully this is actually a webservice not currently in use other than by an outside developer working on an app for another system, so only one request queued. I am looking at cfadmin settings more closely as I just noticed some don't show up on settings summary page

Comment: Dan - ok, so where are you totally the time it takes - on the developer's box?

Comment: I have been using a cf test script and SoapUI to determine response times. Internal to the function I am outputting start/end tickcount difference and time in error string of our response object.

Comment: Ok... so your dev is doing the same thing? He's using a test script on his local dev box to hit the web service on your production server? So the count includes network request time? or do you count the time it takes to build the response on the prod server as well? Trying to isolate the possiblity of network/bandwidth issues eh.

Comment: Another production server that is setup very similarly to the production I'm currently working on has a webservice that was the base for the code I'm currently working on and it is not running into an issue.

Comment: I'm actually referring to my dev box vs production so I'm running all the same tests and just flipping around webservices urls.

Comment: (whew) .. I know I'm being bone headed Dan :)  Are the dev and prod boxes on the _same network_? or is one at say Rackspace and the other at your house - something like that?

Comment: dev box at office with me and production server at datacenter. As I mentioned in my description though I actually did a test internal to the production server to rule out network/encryption :-)

Comment: All right - when you are hitting your dev box _from_ production are you using IP address? and using tghe FLQN when going the other way?

Comment: What does the web service itself _do_ dan? Database query? file manipulation? external services?

Comment: In my regular tests I'm hitting production from dev. As an extra test I hit production from internal to production to avoid network issue. Also, and I'm not certain this is useful, the request is presented in the cf monitor during the extended response time with cpu spiking significantly so it seems to be doing something during that period of time.

Comment: Allright - I buy it :)  So what does the service actually DO?

Comment: db call and return contacts

Comment: Dan - with a CPU spike eh? Can you isolate the query time? Maybe you have a parellelism problem or some other issue on your prod db.

Comment: The spike is on the webserver not database server. I tried to layout relevant info about what I've done to figure this out but I was probably too concise. The timing code in the coldfusion method shows that the actual execution time of the code before the return statement is under a second and the starting timestamp I log at the start of the coldfusion method matches up with the start of the request. All the info I have gathered appears to some sort of inefficiency internal to CF/Axis in some way.

Comment: fyi, I posted an update/resolution with new info. Not sure if everything is resolved with our project but looks like we should be able to work through it from here with Axis1.

Comment: Ah... tricky! I'm glad you have it narrowed down and a work around.